# Solving the system $A = \alpha\cot\theta + \beta\cot\varphi$, $B = \gamma\cos\theta + \delta\cos\varphi$ for $\theta$ and $\varphi$

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I am looking to solve the following system of equations for $\theta, \varphi \in (0, \pi/2]$. Please note that both the trigonometric cotangents and cosines are involved.

$$
A = \alpha\cot(\theta) + \beta\cot(\varphi) \\
B = \gamma\cos(\theta) + \delta\cos(\varphi)
$$

with $A, B, \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta \in \mathbb{R}$ all known.

If simplification is needed, I can allow the assumptions

- $B = 0$
- $A, \alpha, \beta, \gamma > 0$
- $\delta < 0$
- $\left|\gamma\right| > \left|\delta\right|$

I have the following questions:

- Does this system of equations permit an analytic solution? If so, how?
- What would be the easiest method for solving this with a scientific programming language?

It's an algebraic nightmare, and I think I'll just be trying to implementing a computational solution (still working on) until someone more clever than me (not hard to find) solves this. Or I'm not going crazy haha.

Comment: In the 1st equation with $A$, $\beta$ multiplies $\cot \theta$? Or it is $\cot \phi$?

Comment: Argh, good catch thanks. I'll edit it.

Comment: What kind of problems have you faced?

Comment: I suppose I should specify, thanks for asking.

Comment: Now that you have fixed/edited. Why don't you solve this equation treating $cot \theta $ and $\cot \phi $ as $x$ and $y$ respectively? Then use elimination method to get $x$ and $y$. Finally get $arc (cot x) $ and $arc(cot y) $. What is the problem? One more hint : A unique solution will exist when $\alpha \delta -\beta \gamma \ne 0$

Comment: Well, should I introduce variables $u = \cos(\theta)$ and $u = \cos(\varphi)$ as well? It's either $x$ and $y$ become an algebraic mess, or four equations with four unknowns with non-linearity (in which the problem is already non-linear I suppose).

Comment: Ahh. I mis-read the second equation as containing $\cot $ instead of $\cos $.

Comment: Yeah a simple substitution method would've sufficed then, I know haha. Sorry for not making that clear and obvious as my specific issue.

Comment: Through repeated squaring and substitutions you can get to a quartic equation on one of the cosines. It ain't pretty but you can get a formula from there. If $B=0$ then the quartic equation is a biquadratic and that should make the formula more palatable.

Comment: Yes, I did start doing that... it got quite involved. Might as well feed it to some symbolic algebra programming language like Wolfram Alpha. But I ain't paying for that lol.

Comment: You could also try the rational parametrization of the circle.
Let $\cos(\theta) = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and $\sin(\theta) = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ for some $0< t \leqslant 1$, and similarly for $\varphi$ and $u$.

Then

$$A = \alpha\frac{1-t^2}{2t} + \beta\frac{1-u^2}{2u}$$
$$B = \gamma\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} + \delta\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}$$

You get only squares in $t$ and $u$ so maybe the end result is more tractable.

Comment: That's an awesome idea, I've forgotten all about $t$-substitutions. I've given a big *sigh* and started working on it. Thanks. I might post my answer here afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

$$\cot\psi=(A-\alpha\cot\theta)/\beta$$

$$\cos\psi=(B-\gamma\cos\theta)/\delta$$

Now use $$\dfrac1{\cos^2\psi}-\dfrac1{\cot^2\psi}=1$$ to form an equation in $\theta$

Comment: Nice! Regardless of which method I choose I always get a degree six equation, but this gets me there the easiest!